# rvest - scraping links from a webpage

Tags: r, url, web-scraping

I have created this dataframe through rvest:

```
## 00. Pick the webpage
FAO_Countries <- read_html("http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/en/")


## 01. Get the urls I am interested in
FAO_Countries_urls <- FAO_Countries %>% 
html_nodes(".linkcountry") %>% 
html_attr("href")


## 02. Get the links I am interested in
FAO_Countries_links <- FAO_Countries %>%
html_nodes(".linkcountry") %>% 
html_text()


## 03. Prepare the complete urls
url <- "http://www.fao.org"


## 04. Create a dataframe
FAO_Countries_data <- data.frame(FAO_Countries_links =FAO_Countries_links,
                             FAO_Countries_urls = paste0(url,FAO_Countries_urls), 
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Ok. Ath this point, the result I get is this:

```
> head(FAO_Countries_data, n=4)  
  FAO_Countries_links           FAO_Countries_urls

       1 Afghanistan            http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/en/?iso3=AFG
       2 Albania                http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/en/?iso3=ALB
       3 Algeria                http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/en/?iso3=DZA
       4 Andorra                http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/en/?iso3=AND
```

And so on. 
Any of the urls leads to a page in which there is a common element with the other ones. As a matter of fact, any Country is analysed the same way. 
I would be interested in "Food security".
In order to collect info, I would create some new variable. 
The most urgent one would be, indeed, "Food security caught from any urls.
Finally, the dataframe should appear as follows:

```
> head(FAO_Countries_data, n=4)  
  FAO_Countries_links    FAO_Countries_urls                   Food_Sec       
  1 Afghanistan          http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles... BLABLA
```

In fact, I should be able - I suppose - to get those urls from the dataframe's variable "FAO_Countries_urls" as real urls and then scrape them. Or maybe there is another way out. 
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

P.S: Yes, I am using 'Selectorgadget'

Comment: I think that your urls are wrong...for instance this `http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/en/countryprofiles/index/en/?iso3=AFG`, should be `http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/index/en/?iso3=AFG`

Comment: That was a copying errorm actually.
Anyway, the url is 
`http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/index/en/?iso3=AFG`

Comment: That url returns a 404 message :)

Comment: Anyway...once you have all the right url you should iterate over each of one and then get the `food sec` link and save them...then navigate to each food sec url, scrap the content that you need and then stored that in your main dataframe

Comment: Yes, that was my option.
I just wondered whether there is a quicker way to sort out what I need...It's 194 Countries, after all.

Comment: It looks like all the pages for "Food Security" have `&paia=2` appended to the country level URL. So if you want the URL for these pages, you could do: `FAO_Countries_data$Food_Sec <- paste0(FAO_Countries_data$FAO_Countries_urls, "&paia=2")`

Comment: Nice @sinQueso ....one step less